# Compile error - can somebody please correct me?

Tags: java, string, args

I just created a code which represents the sum of integer values from 1 to 10.

```
public class ArithmeticProgress {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 10;
        int n;
        System.out.println(arithmeticprogress(n, i));
    }

    static int arithmeticprogress(int n, int i) {
        int result = n;
        for (n = 0; n < i; n++)
            result += result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile and therefore it only shows error. Can somebody tell me how to correct this code? Thank you!

Comment: You code logic is wrong for sum of integer from 1 to 10. please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `n` here.

```
int n=10; // initialize n to some value
System.out.println(arithmeticprogress(n, i)); //else you will get error here
```

Use `IDE` to coding. Then you will get

```
int n;
System.out.println(arithmeticprogress(n, i));//'n' might not be initialize
```

Or else you can use n as class level variable. Then it will set to it's default value.

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick response! I tried that way, but it shows the completely different value - 10240.

Comment: @MarshallLee you need to initialize `n` with proper value.

Answer (score 1):

As `int n;` declare in method main, it won't be initialized as it is a local variable and local variable are not initialized automatically. You need to initialize it explicitly before use. So changing it to `int n=0;` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting compilation error because in java local variables are stack variables and they must be initialized before they can be used. In your case variable n is used before it is initialized. Initialized it like this and it should work.

```
int n= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem in your code.
**1.** You must need to initialize local variable before to use it. You need to initialize `n` to `0` or `any other value` which is applicable for your logic.

**2.** If you want to get the sum of integer from 1 to 10 than your logic is incorrect that's why you got 1024 as a result ( If you initialize n=1 ). you are adding your current result to previous result which is incorrect. To simply add integer from 1 to 10 i think you didn't need variable `n` in you code.

For this your method should be as shown below :

```
static int arithmeticprogress(int i) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n <=i; n++)
        result = result + n;
    return result;
}
```

It will gives you result as `55` which is summation of 1 to 10 integer number.

May this will help you.